# How do i get the count of products in my db?

Tags: asp.net-core

UPDATE:
I am trying to achieve something like this

id  name

1   TShirts (245 in stock)

2   TShirts ( 170 in stock)

3   Trousers ( 400 in stock)

I have a hierachy of categories to the product listing.

How do I get the count of each product in my code below

something like this

```
products = u.Department_Category_Registration.Products.Count();  (For each
```

unique product e.g. TShirts(12 in stock) , Trousers (200 in stock) , shoes (100 in stock)

which has been commented out in the code below

```
    return View(await _context.Departments_SubCategory_Registration.Include(c =>        c.Departments_Category_Registration)
            .Where(d => d.Departments_Category_Registration.Category_Name.Contains(C))
              .Where(r => r.IsEnabled == true).Select(u => new      Departments_SubCategory_Registration
              {
                  CategoryID = u.CategoryID,
                  SubCategory_Name = u.SubCategory_Name,
                  EntryDate = u.EntryDate,
                  Description_Detailed = u.Description_Detailed,
                  Description_Short = u.Description_Short 

                // e.g. I am trying to get 
                // products = u.Department_Category_Registration.Products.Count();

              }).ToListAsync());
```

UPDATED - Here are my models
1. products
2. Department_Category_Registration
3. Department_subCategory_Registration

the top hierachy is from 3 navigating to 1

```
public class Products
{
    [Key]
    public int ProductID { get; set; }
    public string Product_Name { get; set; }
    public int SupplierID { get; set; }
    public int SubCategoryID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("SubCategoryID")]
    public Departments_SubCategory_Registration Departments_SubCategory_Registration { get; set; }
    public DateTime EntryDate { get; set; }
    public string Product_Code { get; set; }
    public string Description_Short { get; set; }
    public string Description_Long { get; set; }
    public decimal Price_Unit { get; set; }
    public decimal? Price_Advert { get; set; }
    public bool Stock { get; set; }
    public bool IsEnabled { get; set; }

}




public class Departments_SubCategory_Registration
{
    [Key]
    public int SubCategoryID { get; set; }              // This is the PK

  //  [ForeignKey("DepartmentID")]
    public int CategoryID  { get; set; } // this is a FK
    [ForeignKey("CategoryID")]
    public Departments_Category_Registration Departments_Category_Registration { get; set; }


    [ForeignKey("SubCategoryID")]
    public Products Products { get; set; }
    public string SubCategory_Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime EntryDate { get; set; }
    public string Description_Short { get; set; }
    public string Description_Detailed { get; set; }
    public string Notes { get; set; }
   // public string Reference { get; set; }
    public Guid UniqueId { get; set; }
    public bool IsEnabled { get; set; }


}




public class Departments_Category_Registration
{



    [Key]
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }              // This is the PK


    public int DepartmentID { get; set; } // this is a FK

    [ForeignKey("DepartmentID")]
    public Xadosh.Models.Department.Departments Departments { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CategoryID")]
    public Departments_SubCategory_Registration Departments_SubCategory_Registrations { get; set; }
    //public List<Departments_SubCategory_Registration> Departments_SubCategory_Registrations { get; set; }
    public string Category_Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime EntryDate { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Description_Detail { get; set; }
    public string Notes { get; set; }
    public string Reference { get; set; }
    public Guid UniqueId { get; set; }
    public bool IsEnabled { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: It is not clear about your question.Could you share your models of `Department_Category_Registration` and `Product`?`u.Department_Category_Registration.Products.Count();` could only get all the number of Products  in a Category

Comment: What you like to get is more like a view model, is it?The `Products` property in `Departments_SubCategory_Registration` is one Product.still not clear what do you want to get and why you get it in `Select` of linq

Answer (score 0):

You could create a Dto or ViewModel class which will be better describing your data:

```
Departments_SubCategory_RegistrationViewModel
{
 public int CategoryID  { get; set; } 
 public string SubCategory_Name { get; set; }
 public DateTime EntryDate { get; set; }
 public string Description_Short { get; set; }
 public string Description_Detailed { get; set; }
 public int ProductsCount { get; set; }
}
```

And then you should do what you want with this query:

```
return View(
    await _context.Departments_SubCategory_Registration
        .Include(c => c.Departments_Category_Registration)
        .Where(d => d.Departments_Category_Registration.Category_Name.Contains(C))
        .Where(r => r.IsEnabled == true)
        .Select(u => new Departments_SubCategory_RegistrationViewModel
          {
              CategoryID = u.CategoryID,
              SubCategory_Name = u.SubCategory_Name,
              EntryDate = u.EntryDate,
              Description_Detailed = u.Description_Detailed,
              Description_Short = u.Description_Short 
              ProductsCount = u.Products.Count();
          }).ToListAsync());
```

Comment: there is no option for count in u.products.count()

Comment: Oh yes, I see this now. You should change the name of class `Products` to the singular form `Product`. Can you change the type of property Products in `Departments_SubCategory_Registration` class from `Products` to `List<Product>`?